# Information Issues while connecting Hbase remotely

Tags: hadoop, hbase, java

This is the output file of running the java program remotely.

```
> Opening socket connection to server, Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL error, I'm facing this error, when i'm connecting remotely only.

15/10/01 17:00:21 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server quickstart.cloudera/192.168.0.106:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/10/01 17:00:21 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /192.168.0.105:63654, server: quickstart.cloudera/192.168.0.106:2181
15/10/01 17:00:21 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/192.168.0.106:2181, sessionid = 0x150220e67060034, negotiated timeout = 60000
15/10/01 17:00:21 WARN util.DynamicClassLoader: Failed to identify the fs of dir hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase/lib, ignored
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

This is the output file of running the java program locally.

```
15/10/01 13:22:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /127.0.0.1:2181
15/10/01 13:22:36 INFO client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
15/10/01 13:22:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
15/10/01 13:22:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x150220e67060028, negotiated timeout = 60000
15/10/01 13:22:36 WARN util.DynamicClassLoader: Failed to identify the fs of dir hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase/lib, ignored
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

My questions are:

- Am I not able to create a new table in hbase remotely?
- Is there any issue from output file related to my question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you are able to create new tables and perform any other operation with
   HBase remotely.
2. Looks like your error means that you don't add Hadoop or HBase libraries
   properly to your project. As a result your program couldn't find classes of HDFS file system.
   Do you add jars to your project directly or use Maven/Gradle? What dependencies your project have in addition to HBase?

Comment: Hey Max, thankx for the reply. And now i can fix the error. But still One Final more:

Comment: 15/10/05 12:41:52 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/192.168.0.101:2181, sessionid = 0x1503670c5dc0014, negotiated timeout = 60000
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF
 
quickstart.cloudera??????* : this are my library files which i added in my project, everything i downloaded from Maven Website: commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar
hbase-0.92.0.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
zookeeper-3.4.2.jar

Comment: Are you sure that all your dependencies? Because you need hbase-client-*.jar included to perform remote operations with HBase. Be sure to use the same version HBase client library as server library. In your case it's 0.92. If you are using different versions the described issue could be occured.

Comment: I have added those jar files too, but same error:                                                                                                                15/10/05 20:08:21 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/192.168.0.101:2181, sessionid = 0x1503670c5dc008c, negotiated timeout = 60000
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF
 
quickstart.cloudera?????*